# How do I prove this identity ${1\over x}(z-y)-{1\over y}(x+z)+{1\over z}(x-y)=6?$

Tags: trigonometry

$x=\tan(A)$, $y=\tan(60-A)$ and $z=\tan(60+A)$

Show that

$${1\over x}(z-y)-{1\over y}(x+z)+{1\over z}(x-y)=6$$

I try:

$yz(z-y)-xz(x+z)+xy(x-y)=6xyz$

$z-y={\sqrt{3}-\tan(A)\over 1+\sqrt{3}\tan(A)}-{\sqrt{3}+\tan(A)\over 1-\sqrt{3}\tan(A)}={8\tan(A)\over 3\tan^2(A)-1}$

$x+z=\tan(A)+{\sqrt{3}+\tan(A)\over 1-\sqrt{3}\tan(A)}={2\tan(A)+\sqrt{3}(1-\tan^2(A))\over 1-\sqrt{3}\tan(A)}$

$x-y=\tan(A)+{\sqrt{3}-\tan(A)\over 1-\sqrt{3}\tan(A)}={2\tan(A)-\sqrt{3}(1-\tan^2(A))\over 1+\sqrt{3}\tan(A)}$

This method I doing right now seem tedious. It is there an easy route of proving this equation? For now I will  try to prove it this way, please let me know if you have an easy way.

I got to

$${8x(3-x^2)\over (1-3x^2)^2}-{x(\sqrt{3}+x)(2x+\sqrt{3}(1-x^2))\over (1-x\sqrt{3})^2}+{x(\sqrt{3}-x)(2x-\sqrt{3}(1-x^2))\over (1+x\sqrt{3})^2}={6x(3-x^2)\over 1-3x^2}$$

Comment: I just verify it works nicely. I can't see contradiction